# Batch file commands to remove files from network drive

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, unc

I'm trying to remove application logs from shared drive for periodically,

```
ForFiles /p "\\netapp-1\Transfers\Logs\QA" /s /d -15 /c "cmd /c del @file"
```

The above command is working when the path is my local drive, but its not working for shared drive, any help will be highly appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: `pushd "\\netapp-1\Transfers\Logs\QA" && (ForFiles /s /d -15 /c "cmd /c del @file" & popd)`

Comment: UNC paths are not well supported by `cmd`, so use `net use Z: "\\netapp-1\Transfers\Logs\QA"`, then do `forfiles /S /P "Z:\." /D -15 /C "cmd /C if @isdir==FALSE del @path"`, then do `net use Z: /DELETE`...

Answer (score 5):

`ForFiles.exe` does not support UNC paths as the starting directory to start searching from, thus you have to temporarily map a `<Drive Letter>:` to the network path.

And the most convenient way to this, is to use `pushd/popd` command pair to do the MAP/UNMAP automatically, without concerning ourselves with which drive letters are currently available for mapping.

```
pushd "\\netapp-1\Transfers\Logs\QA" && (ForFiles /s /d -15 /c "cmd /c if @isdir==FALSE del @path" & popd)
```

In a batch file the above can be written in multiple lines for better readability

```
pushd "\\netapp-1\Transfers\Logs\QA" && (
    ForFiles /s /d -15 /c "cmd /c if @isdir==FALSE del @path"
    popd
)
```

And there are two flaws in your `ForFiles` command sample that I didn't pay attention to when I was providing the preliminary solution in the comments section, which has been addresses by [aschipfl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5047996/aschipfl) in the comments:

- The directories should be excluded from processing by `if @isdir==FALSE` to not pass them to the `del` command
- The `@path` variable should be used instead of `@file`, to pass the fully qualified paths to the `del` command otherwise it can not files the in the subdirectories to delete them.

**Important Note:**

Note the usage of conditional operator - double ampersands `&&` (which is different from single `&` - command separator) after the `pushd` command. It guarantees `ForFiles`(and `popd`) will be executed **If and only If**, the prior `pushd` command was successful.

It protects the files in current directory from being accidentally deleted in case the `pushd` command fails to map the network path or fails to switch the directory to that path. 
So take it seriously.